# Find a diffeomorphism of R that is not a linear function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this question from In V.I.Arnold's book about ordinary differential equations.

Examples from Boyce and di Prima:

- Find a diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R$ that is not a linear function.

I know that a diffeomorphism is an isomorphism of smooth manifolds. It is an invertible function that maps one differentiable manifold to another such that both the function and its inverse are smooth.

Since any manifold can be locally parametrised, we can consider some explicit maps from $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^2$.

But i couldn't solve it, so please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x^3+x$ is such a diffeomorphism. $f'(x)=3x^2+1>0$ implies that $f$ is strictly increasing, $lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ implies that $f$ is surjective since its image is connected, thus an interval.